# css media query issue only in IE8

Tags: css, media-queries

Why does the following media query work in Google Chrome (23.0), Firefox (16.0.2) and IE9 browsers but not in IE8?

```
@media all and (min-width:720px){
  /* relevant css in here */
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IE8 [doesn't support media queries](http://caniuse.com/css-mediaqueries), you'll need to use a javascript library like [Respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) if you want that functionality in older browsers

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that IE doesn't undderstand media queries.

Try this [link](http://www.webmonkey.com/2011/04/how-to-have-your-media-queries-and-eat-ie-too/)